# A group of order $2^67$

Tags: finite-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $2^6\times 7$. Also $G$ has at least $5$ irreducible characters of degree $7$. I want to prove that with this condition there exists no character of even degree in $G$ (or equivalently the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is normal and abelian).

Could you help me about it?

Comment: Hmm, this is a tricky one. So, at least if the number of irreducibles of degree $7$ is odd, you get that the $2$-Sylow is normal, but it seems to require a further argument (that I am not seeing right now) to get it to be abelian even in that case.